# tictactoe iteration issue. Function error

Tags: function, python-3.x, parameters

I am new to programming (About 2 months in to teaching myself). I am attempting to create a game of tic tac toe and use it as an opportunity to practice using functions and passing parameters.

I have got most of what I want to work working (for now I will add AI and a computer opponent) but when one of the human players win the endgame() function is called but it does not work as expected. It calls itself somehow and you have got to say N to end the game three times before the program is terminated. I am unable to see the wood for the trees on this one folks so help would be appreciated.

I know some of my coding will not be great so no trolling please.

Thanks

Shaun

```
def start():

    choices = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
    while checkwin(choices)==False:
        board(choices)
        getchoice(choices)

def board(choices):

    print("+---+---+---+")
    print("+ "+choices[0]+" + "+choices[1]+" + "+choices[2]+" +")
    print("+---+---+---+")
    print("+ "+choices[3]+" + "+choices[4]+" + "+choices[5]+" +")
    print("+---+---+---+")
    print("+ "+choices[6]+" + "+choices[7]+" + "+choices[8]+" +")
    print("+---+---+---+")

def endgame(winner):

    print("The winner is "+ winner)
    playagain=input("Another game? Y/N")
    playagain = playagain.upper()
    if playagain == "N":
        print("Thanks, hope to see you again soon.")
    else:
        start()


def getchoice(choices):

    userchoice = int(input ("Where would you like to put your X?"))
    index = userchoice-1
    while choices[index]!=" ":
        userchoice = int(input ("That space is taken. Where would you like to put your X?"))
        index = userchoice-1

    choices[index]="X"
    board(choices)
    if checkwin(choices)==False:
        userchoice = int(input ("Where would you like to put your O?"))
        index = userchoice-1
        while choices[index]!=" ":
            userchoice = int(input ("That space is taken. Where would you like to put your O?"))
            index = userchoice-1

        choices[index]="O"
    checkwin(choices)
    return choices

def checkwin (c):

    if checkwin1(c)==False:
        if checkwin2 (c)==False:
            return False
        else:
            endgame("Player 2")
    else:
        endgame("Player 1")

def checkwin1(c):   

    return ((c[0]=="X" and c[1]=="X" and c[2]=="X") or
(c[3]=="X"and c[4]=="X" and c[5] =="X") or
(c[6]=="X"and c[7]=="X" and c[8] =="X") or
(c[0]=="X"and c[3]=="X" and c[6] =="X" )or
(c[1]=="X"and c[4]=="X" and c[7] =="X") or
(c[2]=="X"and c[5]=="X" and c[8] =="X") or
(c[0]=="X"and c[4]=="X" and c[8] =="X") or
(c[6]=="X"and c[4]=="X" and c[2] =="X"))

def checkwin2(c):   

    return ((c[0]=="O" and c[1]=="O" and c[2]=="O") or
(c[3]=="O"and c[4]=="O" and c[5] =="O") or
(c[6]=="O"and c[7]=="O" and c[8] =="O") or
(c[0]=="O"and c[3]=="O" and c[6] =="O" )or
(c[1]=="O"and c[4]=="O" and c[7] =="O") or
(c[2]=="O"and c[5]=="O" and c[8] =="O") or
(c[0]=="O"and c[4]=="O" and c[8] =="O") or
(c[6]=="O"and c[4]=="O" and c[2] =="O"))

start()
```

Comment: `endgame()` doesn't call itself when 'N' is entered, not even indirectly. Instead -- some other code is calling `endgame()` more than once.

Comment: Not relevent to the question: You may want to think about the case of how to terminate a game when the game finishes with no player winning.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine that X wins (because this is probably what caused it to "end") three times.

You then get to `if checkwin(choices)==False:` within `getchoice()`,
'checkwin()' happily calls `endgame()`. `endgame()` returns, and then `getchoice()` continues executing.

At the end of `getchoice()`, `checkwin()` is called again, with the same result.

After `getchoice()` returns we get back to `while checkwin(choices)==False:` within `start()`, once again with the same result.

Also note that you will see this happening even more times if you actually played multiple games in a row.

Also try making O win, I think you will only have to say no to your prompt twice in that case.

EDIT:

```
class TicTacToeGame:
    INCOMPLETE = 0
    WINNER_PLAYER_1 = 1
    WINNER_PLAYER_2 = 2
    DRAW = 3

    SYMBOLS=["X","O"," "]

    def __init__(self,player_1, player_2):
        self.board = [[-1]*3,[-1]*3,[-1]*3]
        self.players = [player_1,player_2]
        self.current_turn = 0;

    def advance(self):
        if self.calcGameState() != TicTacToeGame.INCOMPLETE:
            return
        while True:
            x,y = self.players[self.current_turn].getMove();
            if x < 0 or x > 2 or y < 0 or y>2 :
                continue
            if self.board[y][x] == -1:
                break
        self.board[y][x] = self.current_turn
        self.current_turn += 1
        self.current_turn %= 2

    def stringify(self):
        re = ""
        fr = True
        for row in self.board:
            if fr:
                fr=False
            else:
                re+= "\n" + "---+" * 2 + "---\n"
            fe = True
            for el in row :
                if fe:
                    fe = False;
                else:
                    re += "|"
                re += " " + TicTacToeGame.SYMBOLS[el] + " "
        return re

    def calcGameState(self):
        for i in range(0,3):
            #col
            if all(self.board[i][j] == self.board[i][0] for j in range(0,3)) and self.board[i][0] != -1:
                return self.board[i][0] + 1
            #row
            if all(self.board[j][i] == self.board[0][i] for j in range(0,3)) and self.board[0][i] != -1:
                return self.board[0][i] + 1
        if all(self.board[i][i] == self.board[0][0] for i in range(0,3)) and self.board[0][0] != -1:
            return self.board[0][0] + 1
        if all(self.board[i][2-i] == self.board[0][2] for i in range(0,3)) and self.board[0][2] != -1:
            return self.board[0][2] + 1
        if all(self.board[i][j] != -1 for i in range(0,3) for j in range(0,3)):
            return TicTacToeGame.DRAW
        return TicTacToeGame.INCOMPLETE

    def stringResult(self):
        res = self.calcGameState()
        if res == TicTacToeGame.INCOMPLETE:
            return "Incomplete"
        if res == TicTacToeGame.DRAW:
            return "Draw"
        return "Player " + self.SYMBOLS[res-1] + " Won!"

class HumanPlayer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = None

    def setGame(self,game):
        self.game = game

    def getMove(self):
        print(self.game.stringify())
        print("Current turn is: " + self.game.SYMBOLS[self.game.current_turn])
        print("enter row for move")
        y = input()
        print("enter col for move")
        x = input()
        return int(x)-1,int(y)-1

def playAgain():
    playagain=input("Another game? Y/N\n > ")
    playagain = playagain.upper()
    if playagain == "N":
        print("Thanks, hope to see you again soon.")
        return False
    return True

while True:
    p = HumanPlayer()
    t = TicTacToeGame(p,p)
    p.setGame(t)

    while t.calcGameState() == TicTacToeGame.INCOMPLETE:
        t.advance()
    print(t.stringResult())
    if not playAgain():
        break;
```

Comment: You are correct about that the single echo (as opposed to double-echo) when it is O that wins. When I downloaded OP's code and tried to reproduce the bug I just had to say 'N' twice. I noticed that `checkwin()` at the end of `getchoice()` and that seemed like an adequate explanation of why I saw the echo but I hadn't yet untangled why OP was having to do it three times. Nice debugging job.

Comment: I have tried to amend my program based on the information above but am still falling short. I can get the program to end every time with the player using O but still need to choose end program twice if I play as the player X. As above if I play multiple games I have to end the game even more time e.g. If I play two games I have to choose end game three times. Any further thoughts?

Comment: The easy way to ensure that you exit is to use sys.exit - https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit - as soon as you want to exit. However, I would recommend that you reconsider your approach to this program and maybe learn something along the way.

Comment: @ShaunRogers Or if you feel like seeing a way that one might go about doing this: https://repl.it/BCIO let me know if you have any questions about what's going on in that, but please try to research any concepts you don't yet know about by yourself first. (also code in answer edit soon). This is intended as an example and is not perfect, in many ways, so keep that in mind while you read it.